# Python unittest mock ... mock a module statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking, xbmc

I'm having difficuly getting my head around python's mock test methodology.

I want to do some mocking on [this file](https://github.com/powlo/weather.metoffice/blob/master/src/metoffice/setlocation.py).

Since packages xbmc, xbmcaddon and xbmcgui cannot be imported in a normal python environment I've managed to mock them out like this:

```
class XBMCTestCase(unittest.TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        #Mock up any calls to modules that cannot be imported
        self.xbmc = Mock()
        self.xbmcgui = Mock()
        self.xbmcaddon = Mock()

        modules = {
            'xbmc' : self.xbmc,
            'xbmcgui': self.xbmcgui,
            'xbmcaddon': self.xbmcaddon
            }
        self.module_patcher = patch.dict('sys.modules', modules) #@UndefinedVariable
        self.module_patcher.start()
```

See it in action [here](https://github.com/powlo/weather.metoffice/blob/master/src/test/test_urlcache.py).

So when I import setlocation.py I get an error like this:

```
  File "/home/paulo/workspace/weather.metoffice/src/metoffice/utils/utilities.py", line 21, in <module>
    CACHE_FOLDER = os.path.join(ADDON_DATA_PATH, 'cache')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 78, in join
    path +=  b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Mock' and 'str'
```

Even if I mock out 'metoffice.utils' (by adding it to the list of modules in the patch created at setup) I get a similar error in `setlocation.py`

```
  File "/home/paulo/workspace/weather.metoffice/src/metoffice/setlocation.py", line 32, in <module>
    GEOIP_PROVIDER = int(__addon__.getSetting('GeoIPProvider'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Mock'
```

So I need `__addon__.getSetting()` to return a string.

Any ideas?

All attempts have failed, but I don't think I have a full grasp of the capabilities of the mock package.

Note I'm on Python 2.7.3 with [mock 1.0.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)

Comment: Where does `__addon__` come from? If you have mocked out that object, you need to make sure that you set a return value for the `getSetting()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your mocks what to return. The `__addon__` value is the result of a `xbmcaddon.Addon()` call, so you can get access to that mock object with:

```
addon = self.xbmcaddon.Addon.return_value
```

because `.return_value` gives you the actual `Mock` object that calling `Addon()` would return.

Now you can tell that `Mock` object what to return when the `getSetting()` method is called; there are two values to provide here, so you could use the [`side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) to set a sequence of values to return:

```
addon.getSetting.side_effect = ['some_api_key', '42']
```

where the first call to `__addon__.getSetting()` will produce the first value `'some_api_key'`, the second cal will produce `'42'`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn that works. It still makes my head hurt because it feels like I'm making changes to an instance that somehow changes the class definition itself.